# How do I write out a multiple choice question in Japanese?

Tags: questions, email

This is more for formal written email than spoken in person.

For example, if I was to ask:

---

Which of the following do you enjoy:

(A) Coffee

(B) Tea

(C) The java in me

---

I would also like to know the most common way of listing a multiple choice such as if I was to use ㋐　㋑　㋒ in this situation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(A)(B)(C) and (1)(2)(3) are perfect choices in most modern Japanese workplaces, especially when you send something via the Internet. ①②③ is the next safest. Some traditional documents still prefer (ア)(イ)(ウ), ㋐㋑㋒ or even [(イ)(ロ)(ハ)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroha#Current_uses), but I don't recommend using them at least as a primarily choice. (If you work at a legal department, there may be special rules to list things.)

[丸囲み文字](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50511/5010) and [組文字](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37132/5010) were common in the pre-internet era, but its use has been discouraged by many people in the last 20 years due to technical reasons regarding character encoding (For example, ㋐㋑㋒ was not commonly available for a while on PC, and Mac users could not even read ①②③ in an email sent by PC users). Now it's generally safe to use them thanks to Unicode, but many people still avoid them on the net.