# What will the new character ⿰令和 look like?

Tags: kanji

On the Wikipedia page for the [Reiwa period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reiwa_period) there's a section:

> **Implementation**
>
> The Unicode Consortium has already reserved a code point (U+32FF) for a new glyph which will combine halfwidth versions of reiwa's kanji, 令 and 和, into a single full-width character.

I'm finding it hard to imagine what ⿰令和 will look like though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since it is two characters put in a square for typographic consideration on legacy environments, not meant to be a single character, no stylistic adjustment would be made and it would just look like two compressed characters adjacent to each other.

Some Adobe staffs seemingly begin to work on the new glyph. He says the right shape should be the second one.

[image]
(https://twitter.com/ken_lunde/status/1112556766233948165)

---

cf. past era names...

[image]
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Compatibility)

Comment: I found this article, also written by Ken Lunde, after reading your answer: https://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2019/03/era-name-ligature-history.html

Comment: And this is a relevant question in this site: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37132/5010